# Website that allows me to properly run C++ code that uses cin?

Tags: java, c++

Is there a website where I can run Java or C++ code online that lets me use `cin` in c++? Codepad and many others just let you see your program but don't let the user provide input, and I wanted to know if I could find a website that allows that.

Ideone doesn't seem to do the input right : This is supposed to be a game where you enter a word then the letter changes places, and then you need to figure out the word. The code is correct but the website doesnt read the cin right ! http://ideone.com/0PmDX

Comment: Why don't you just install a compiler locally?

Comment: As per your posted code: http://ideone.com/0PmDX, ideone _did_ read cin right.  You ran the program with no input, and it did exactly what you coded it to do in the situation where there is no input.  Also, all the `system` calls failed.

Comment: Also, you say that the code is correct, but it clearly isn't.  Namely, you never check that the input works, causing an infinite loop when you reach the end of the stream.  This is a bug in your code.  Also, in the ideone run, _you gave it no input to run with_.  I no of no online tool that allows feedback like a console, Ideone and others require all input to be entered before the program compiles.

Comment: Also Rapptz just spotted that you `return main();` which is strange, illegal, and makes the program repeat infinitely.

Answer (score 10):

[Ideone does just that](http://ideone.com/) this is also in the Info section of the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

In your provided code: http://ideone.com/0PmDX you call `return main();` which is undefined behaviour and is causing your infinite loops in your code. Try `return 0` instead.

Code: http://ideone.com/ymXeH

Comment: The only thing I don't like about ideone is that you can't pass command line arguments.  It's easy enough to get around though, you can just have your `main` call another function `Main` or something and manually set up the argument list yourself.

Comment: @Wug, Or just have a `static const char *argv[] = {"program name", "arg1", "arg2"};` at the top of `main()`.

Comment: I use ideone for code golf a lot.  As such, I try to use methods that are easy to account for when counting characters.  For example: http://ideone.com/nQi9V (all I have to do to count the characters is to leave out the actual main function)